# Google Maps API suddenly stopped working on my spreadsheet

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I use the Google Maps Directions API for a custom function in Excel, to find the distance and travel time between two postcodes.

Out of nowhere, this morning, it's stopped working.

I noticed that Google maps no longer puts a pin in a post code when you search for a post code. It just highlights an area. Could this be causing a new issue?

Or is it more likely to be something locally?

My TRAVELTIME and TRAVELDISTANCE formulas now result in #VALUE errors.

I've just opened a previous version that we know was working this morning and yesterday, to see if we might have accidentally broken something throughout the day, but we're getting the same issue. So that implies it's something to something to do with the API, or maybe the JSON in the background.

This is the VBA for one of the custom functions, if it helps:

```
Function TRAVELTIME(origin, destination, apikey)

Dim strUrl As String
strUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" & origin & "&destination=" & destination & "&key=" & apikey
 
Set httpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
With httpReq
     .Open "GET", strUrl, False
     .Send
End With
 
Dim response As String
response = httpReq.ResponseText
 
Dim parsed As Dictionary
Set parsed = Module2.ParseJson(response)
Dim seconds As Integer
 
Dim leg As Dictionary
 
For Each leg In parsed("routes")(1)("legs")
    seconds = seconds + leg("duration")("value")
Next leg
 
 
 
TRAVELTIME = seconds
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. We reached our quota for the day. Now I feel stupid.

I had checked on the console, but I think it hadn't refreshed.